# Select similar classes and append it to the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 different divs inside an id. (screenshot below).

I want to select each `itslocked` div and append it to the last so the normal div should appear on the top and all `itslocked` div appears after that.

[image]

```
$("#rewardCount").find(".itslocked").each(function() {
    $lock_content=$(this);   
    $(".itslocked").remove();             
    console.log($lock_content[0].outerHTML); 
    $("#rewardCount").append($lock_content[0].outerHTML);
});
```

The above code is only appending single `itslocked` div and all other gets removed. How do I fixed it so the all itslocked div line up at the bottom?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look [at this](https://api.jquery.com/detach/). Why are you removing all the elements in the loop (`$(".itslocked").remove();`)?

Comment: please post you html code instead of an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing all divs in your loop.

Try this:

```
$(".itslocked", $("#rewardCount")).appendTo("#rewardCount");
```

Comment: I think you can just do it in one go `$("#rewardCount").append( $("#rewardCount .itslocked").detach() );` - But your solution should work perfectly as it is

Comment: Why do elements have to be detached before appending them into another container? Calling `append()` will not copy but move them anyway.

Comment: Good question @Stphane, it's not needed at all. I'm editing the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the multiple answers with explanation. However it is now edited I got to learn something new. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace 
    $(".itslocked").remove;

With
    $(this).remove();

Sine you have a loop, you don't to remove all elemtes on the first iteration